# Setting and accessing document-level variables in Acrobat 10 Pro

Tags: javascript, variables, acrobat

I have a form that currently functions based on in-field calculations.  In order to get some of the calculations to work, I had to create hidden calculated fields and then calculate off of the those hidden fields to get other calculations.

(This is a loan application form, so there are many variables, such as credit score, interest rate based off credit score, loan term, etc.)

I want to move the hidden fields to document-level variables, but can't seem to make the other fields recognize the document-level variables, or calculate based on their (supposed) values.

For example, I have a field that is populated by a series of checkboxes.  Right now, the MouseUp Event Action populates the htxtLoanType using the following script:

```
this.getField("htxt_LoanType").value = "0";
```

This and 2 other similar functions create the 3 values I need to access an array containing all the possible interest rate combinations, based on credit score, loan term and loan type.

I have tried to enter a variable **(outside of a function)** into the Document JavaScripts named "Variables" here...

[image]

```
var vLoanType;          // The array value of the current loan type...
```

I then try to set the value of 'vLoanType' with this script linked to the MouseUp EventScript of the checkbox:

```
//this.getField("htxt_LoanRequestType").value = "0";
vLoanType = "0";
```

The commented section works, since it assigns the value directly to the textfield.  The `vLoanType = "0";` doesn't seem to assign anything to the variable, since I can't get the variable to return a value to a text field.

If I try to enter

```
event.value = vLoanType;
```

into a text field's custom calculation script, it does nothing.  It doesn't return the variable's value, which should be set to "0", and it doesn't display anything.

What am I missing regarding the setting and returning of document-level variables?  I don't code professionally, so any help would be appreciated.  Also, let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Without the functioning form, it's hard to tell what exactly is going on. There may be other calculations stepping on the calculations that you are trying to modify.

Comment: @joelgeraci - I just added the variable declarations in the document level.  No other assignment other than to reference them in a text field has been done.

I think I've figured out the assignment, I just need to figure out how to display a variable's value in a text field.  Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables declared ***outside*** of a function in a document level script (which is not the default when you create a new document level script) are scoped to the PDF document which means that any field can access them. By default, creating a new document level script via Acrobat Pro will create a stub function for you based on the name you entered in the dialog. Delete the function; it's not necessary.

To display a variable's value in a text field, use the following code where "foo" is the variable name and "myField" is the name of the field in question.

```
this.getField("myField").value = foo;
```